# PHP - strtotime using phrase "first day of last week" not correct

Tags: php

Using the code:

```
$from_date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("first day of last week"));
```

returns: "2020-10-01 00:00:00", when I expect it to return "2020-10-25 00:00:00".

Why is it returning the first day of the month?

How can I get the first day of last week (and also the last day of last week)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php

$from_date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("last week last sunday"));

echo $from_date;
//returns 2020-10-25 00:00:00;
```

*I've tested the dates on 7.1.0 version*

Comment: And  I tested on 7.4.12 :)

Comment: Yes that seems to do it... Is there documentation on best phrasing to use for strtotime? Or do you just try moving words around until it works?

Comment: @TedScheckler Moving words is not good, here you can find the [strtotime Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)